# ServiceStack IdentityServer4 - IdentityServerAuthFeature

Tags: servicestack

I want to use IdentityServer with my ServiceStack API, however, when I add this in my Startup.cs in this method: *public override void Configure(Container)*

```
Plugins.Add(new IdentityServerAuthFeature
      {
        AuthProviderType = IdentityServerAuthProviderType.UserAuthProvider,
        AuthRealm = "XXX",             
        ClientId = "YYY",         
        ClientSecret = "ZZZ"
      });
```

And when I wrap my class \ method with `[Authenticate]` and try to access it I'm getting this response:

> {
>     "responseStatus": {
>       "errorCode": "Exception",
>       "message": "No registered Auth Providers found matching IdentityServer provider"
>     }
>   }

Am I missing something?

Here's the actual implementation of this [IdentityServerAuthFeature](https://github.com/wwwlicious/servicestack-authentication-identityserver/blob/7685efe2f6ff2bfd9022e792911330383d603faa/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.IdentityServer/IdentityServerAuthFeature.cs)

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

After some debugging the problem was with `HostConfig`. I forgot to add `WebHostUrl` and I saw that while I was looking later on metadata (`?debug=requestinfo`), the error was:

> ConfigurationException
>   appHost.Config.WebHostUrl must be set to use the Identity Server User Login >plugin so that the service can sent it's full http://url:port to the >Identity Server User Login

Comment: You should include info on the IdentityServerAuthFeature impl you’re using also note that ServiceStack uses [Authenticate] attribute not [Authorize].

Comment: Sorry it was a typo for `Authorize` vs `Authenticate` and I updated the question with link to `IdentityServerAuthFeature`.

Comment: You should also include the full Exception StackTrace and you may want to consider raising an issue with the project and link to this question as the library Author would be best person who can help.

Comment: FYI you’d need to enable [DebugMode](http://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#debugmode) to include StackTraces in responses.

Comment: There was an issue in startup configuration... I forgot to add `WebHostUrl`.

Comment: @mythz have you seen this error before maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001102/missingmethodexception-get-querystring