# MissingMethodException get_QueryString

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I come across this exception in my .net core app (.net core 2.1 and I'm using service stack 5.2).

> Method not found: 'ServiceStack.Web.INameValueCollection ServiceStack.Web.IRequest.get_QueryString()'.

It comes from one of the plugins originally, but I can't figure out why.
Code breaks on this line [here](https://github.com/wwwlicious/servicestack-authentication-identityserver/blob/7685efe2f6ff2bfd9022e792911330383d603faa/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.IdentityServer/Providers/UserAuthProvider.cs#L314).

`session.ReferrerUrl = GetReferrerUrl(authService, session, request);`

Btw, in app console I also get this:

> warn: ServiceStack.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer[0] Property 'redirect' does not exist on type 'ServiceStack.Authenticate'

...but I don't think that's related to the exception above.

Any hints what might be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no [INameValueCollection on IRequest anymore](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/dde1cec921ed7118412bd9b0d310405d9fe369b2/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IRequest.cs#L95) that was replaced last year with `NameValueCollection` from v5+, whatever v4 code you have that's using it needs to be recompiled with the same version as the rest of your project.

To get a clean upgrade make sure all your projects are referencing the same ServiceStack version, delete your `/bin` and `/obj` folders and try restoring from NuGet again.

If it’s still an issue clear your NuGet Cache and restore again:

> warn: ServiceStack.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer[0] Property 'redirect' does not exist on type 'ServiceStack.Authenticate'

This is irrelevant it's just a warning that there was a `redirect` property on Request DTOs, I've added it to the ignore list in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f545ea913db9135eaca52251c03ebca4d0fb1825).

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Comment: I did that, I cleared all `bin` and `obj` folders, updated my ServiceStack to 5.4.1 in all projects, cleared cached nuget packages, but I'm still seeing this same error when I hit my protected API method.

Comment: @ShP You have some old binaries that were compiled against v4 that needs to recompile against the latest version.